# MySQL hex strings low bytes first

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, hex

If I insert `0xFF` into a binary column, MySql (5.7) assumes these are the high bytes.

e.g. if the column is BINARY(2):

```
+--------------------+
| HEX(binary_column) |
+--------------------+
| FF00               |
+--------------------+
```

Just for convenience, how would you get MySql to interpret a hex string normally?

P.S. Also tried UNHEX()

Comment: MySQL doesn't assume high bytes. A `binary(2)` is a string with a fixed lenght of 2, and the remaining parts are filled with `\0` at the end (because it is a string). Use `varbinary(2)` as datatype if you want to simulate bits with strings, or `bit(16)` to have bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`binary` is not really a numerical datatype. It is a special type of string used to store binary data like files. In contrast to e.g. `char`, `binary` does not have a character map and comparisons are done with the numerical code.

That behaviour is similar as to how other programming languages treat strings and byte arrays, and is expected in mysql too, see [The BINARY and VARBINARY Type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/binary-varbinary.html):

> When BINARY values are stored, they are right-padded with the pad value to the specified length. The pad value is 0x00 (the zero byte). Values are right-padded with 0x00 on insert, and no trailing bytes are removed on select. All bytes are significant in comparisons, including ORDER BY and DISTINCT operations. 0x00 bytes and spaces are different in comparisons, with 0x00 < space.

You seem to look for binary numbers, so you may want to use a numeric type. You can use e.g. `int` (or `bit(16)`) and still insert values like `0xFF` (just not as `'0xFF'` without further casting), and you still can display them with e.g. `hex(0xFF)` in the way you want.

If you want to use binary values (or need large values > 8 byte), you can use [lpad](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad) to fill them with leading zeros, e.g.

```
select hex(lpad(0xFF,2,0x0))
```

You have to know (or query) the size of your column, and you will probably run into a lot of issues with this, starting with the simple task of adding two binary values. So to keep it simple, use a numeric type.